# How to pass data from any depth child component to direct its all parent component without emit in nuxt 3

Tags: components, vue-component, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, vue-reactivity

I have some component herarchie as per the below structure

```html
<layout>
  <Header />
      <Main /> //Inside this main component there is many child component depth
  <Footer />
<layout />
```

Here I want one reactive variable from one page component `pages/index.vue` to all its parent components. ex if I have declared `const data = ref(false);` in index.vue page then this variable should be accesable on `Header` `Footer` and default `Layout` as well.

Comment: You can do this with some state management library, for example Pinia (https://nuxt.com/modules/pinia)

Comment: @Mira135 Thank you for your comment. Can you please suggest which is best to manage state nuxt's default useState composable or pinia?

Comment: I personally use Pinia, it's very easy to use and works nice with Nuxt

Comment: @Mira135 Thank you very much for your revert! I will try this. Please vote up so other peoples can also get the same